# Async Task to divide workload

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

**i am trying to divide the work among multiple tasks based on id ranges** 
i have this method that gets start and end ranges based on i.
I can see that the GetRanges method is  dividing the ranges correctly to task.
but when the task gets called StartWork(startRange, endRange) it sometimes sets all task with same range
and sometimes with 2 or three duplicate ranges.
**Basically unique startrange and endRange are not being passed when async task starts? how can i fix it?**

```
        int endRange = 0;
        int startRange = 0;
        int total = GetTotal();
        int startIndex =1;
        for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            GetRanges(ref startRange, ref endRange, total, i, startIndex);             
            Console.WriteLine("startRange {0} EndRange {1}", startRange, endRange);             
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartWork(startRange, endRange));

        }

        private void StartWork(int startRange, int endRange)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}  task startRange {1} EndRange {2}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, startRange, endRange);
        }

        private void GetRanges(ref int startRange, ref int endRange, int total, int threadIndex, int startIndex)
        {
            int averagetask = (total - startIndex) / taskCount;
            startRange = (averagetask * threadIndex) + 1;

            if (threadIndex == taskCount - 1)
            endRange = total;
            else
            endRange = averagetask * (threadIndex + 1);

        }
```

Here is the output
startRange 1 EndRange 785761
startRange 785762 EndRange 1571522
startRange 1571523 EndRange 2357283
startRange 2357284 EndRange 3143047

Thread 3  task startRange 2357284 EndRange 3143047
Thread 5  task startRange 2357284 EndRange 3143047
Thread 4  task startRange 2357284 EndRange 3143047
Thread 6  task startRange 2357284 EndRange 3143047

Comment: are you able to give us the `GetRanges` method body?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer added the methods

Comment: You might want to look in to the [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx) method, it may do the work for you of spiting the work up across cores for you. `Parallel.For(0, GetTotal(), PerformWorkOnAIndex);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with using ref parameters and passing them to tasks on separate threads. I think whats happening is by the time a task looks at the value, its already been changed on another thread. ie your StartWork method is looking at the current value of startRange/endRange, which keeps being changed.

Try doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
{
    GetRanges(ref startRange, ref endRange, total, i, startIndex);             
    Console.WriteLine("startRange {0} EndRange {1}", startRange, endRange);             
    var tempStartRange = startRange;
    var tempEndRange = endRange;
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartWork(tempStartRange, tempEndRange));
}
```

Comment: You're right about the fix, but the problem has nothing to do with the usage of `ref` parameters here.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem?